# Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Unknown error (0xffffffff)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set up NativeScript on Windows. I am following the steps from the site and when I type this:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"
```

I get this error:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Unknown error
(0xffffffff).
At line:25 char:2
+     Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -Wait -Argumen ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: It appears it fails when executing another script from githubusercontent. I would suggest to copy/paste the script to the target system in Powershell ISE, set a breakpoint at line 24, single step, find the line that fails and pick it up from there.

Comment: copy and paste what script to what target system sir??

Comment: With target system I meant the system where you want to install Nativescript.
Based on your script, you can get the initial script as follows:
`(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win')`
Check it out, in the 25th line you will see it calls the PowerShell script at `https://raw.githubuse
rcontent.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/production/setup/native-script.ps1`.